# How to call a function of child activity inside an activity group from parent activity / tab activity?

Tags: android, function, tabactivity, activitygroup, childactivity

Suppose , i have a tab activity consist of a TabHost. The TabHost contains 2 tabs, each of two has an activity group of it. Each activity group contains of one activity. Now , say , Tab Activity is a class A. Two activity groups are class B & class C. B & C , each contains class D & class E. So the hierarchy is,

A
|       |
B     C
|       |
D     E

Now , I want to call a function of class E from Class A when A's onPaused function is called. I tried to get Activity E using local activity manager but got no success. Beside, looked at some possible solution here & on Google also but my luck haven't favored yet. :( So now , i hope my explanation above is clear enough to make people understand exactly what i want. Please guys , help me on the issue with some samples , codes or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution from [here](http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/two-way-communication-between-tabactivity-and-its-child-tabs/). If say more specifically , solved by the block of codes below.

```
ActivityTab1 activity = (ActivityTab1) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("Tab1");
activity.refreshContent();
```